# which XML editor to use for speech recognition grammar specifications (SRGS)

Tags: xml, speech-recognition, xmlwriter, xml-parsing, vxml

Is it best to use a particular editor to write XML or will any editor do?
In particular I will be using XML to write Speech Recognition Grammar Specifications (SRGS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend using an XML-aware editor over a general-purpose text editor. There are many available. I use oXygen, which is very popular in the XML community, but use whatever takes your liking.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Kay. Do you know if Netbeans is considered to be XML-aware?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding SRGS, you should consider authoring your grammars with ABNF format and then convert them to XML form (if really required).  ABNF format is much more concise than the XML format.

The ultimate SRGS editor is NuGram IDE, it's an Eclipse plug-in:
http://nugram.nuecho.com/nugram_ide

This tools performs some syntax-checking, allow coverage testing, grammar debugging and a lot more.  Try it out. The basic edition is free.

Comment: Thanks, @gawi, for the tip about NuGram. For now, I really do need to use XML format.

Comment: Yes but you can go back-and-forth between xML and ABNF format.  That's a nice thing about NuGram IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's information: I was informed offline that netbeans is a good editor to use for XML.